# Как клонировать проект из Git используя SSH который из Vault

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, vault

Столкнулся с проблемой при переносе секретов из Jenkins в Vault.

Не могу понять как правильно использовать ssh для клонирования проекта, если он (ssh) лежит в Vault в Key/Value хранилище.

Перерыл документацию в Jenkins, документацию к плагину, гуглил, решение не нашлось.

Генератор в Pipeline Syntax выдает что-то странное:

```
withCredentials([<object of type com.datapipe.jenkins.vault.credentials.common.VaultSSHUserPrivateKeyBinding>]) {
    // some block
}
```

В Jenkins Credentials создал соответствующие секреты:
vault_approle_dev - с типом "Vault App Role Credential"
vault_tech_user_ssh - имеет тип "Vault SSH Username with private key Credential"

В примере я пытаюсь получить 2 секрета из Vault:
log-pass - успешно достается,
к секрету с ssh доступ есть.

Jenkins общий (корпоративный), поэтому в глобальных настройках плагина не могу указать на конкретный Vault.

Заранее благодарен.

```
node('Linux_Default') {
    stage('Clone project') {
        def configuration = [
                engineVersion: 1,
                timeout: 60,
                vaultCredentialId: 'vault_approle_dev',
                vaultNameSpace: 'SOME_NAMESPACE',
                vaultUrl: 'https://some.vault.host'
        ]

        def secrets = [
                [path: '/LEVEL_1/LEVEL_2/USER/log-pass', secretValues: [
                        [envVar: 'techUserLogin', vaultKey: 'login'],
                        [envVar: 'techUserPassword', vaultKey: 'password'],
                ]]
        ]

        withVault([configuration: configuration, vaultSecrets: secrets]) {
            echo 'Tech user login: $techUserLogin, passwd: techUserPassword'

            withCredentials([
                    [$class: 'VaultSSHUserPrivateKeyBinding', credentialsId: 'vault_tech_user_ssh']
            ]) {
                git branch: 'develop', url: 'ssh://git@my.bitbucket.url:7999/~project-owner/my-project.git'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

В логах Jenkins'a вот такой стектрейс: (текстом не могу приложить)
[image: Стектрейс]